# Does NServiceBus v5.0 require performance counters?

Tags: c#, nservicebus

I recently upgraded my small project from NServiceBus 4.6 to 5.0.1. After smoothing out the interface changes, I now crash at runtime with the message:

> System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
>   Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   Additional information: NServiceBus performance counter for Critical Time is not set up correctly. Please run Install-NServiceBusPerformanceCounters cmdlet to rectify this problem.

I do not use performance counters in my code and would rather not have to install any additional components. I see the same issue with the Sample "VideoStore.SqlServer" on Particular's GitHub page. Do a fresh pull, F5, ... and boom.

Does version 5 of NServiceBus require me to set up their counters by default instead of the opt-in approach of v4.x?

**Edit: 2014-10-21**
Using `config.DisableFeature<CriticalTimeMonitoring>();` I still could not get the sample to run (received same error). Per Adam's suggestion, I opened a [ticket](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/issues/2514) and will update this question when I hear back from Particular on the issue.

Answer (score 4):

In your configuration you can disable the feature: `config.DisableFeature<CriticalTimeMonitoring>();`

Comment: While this appears promising, it does not work. I added this to the configuration for one of Particular's sample services (VideoStore.ContentManagement) and it makes no difference. I still receive the same error message. My team reviewed what I did and we reproduced it on multiple machines before I wrote this reply. I'm stumped.

Comment: Sounds like a bug then, please report on the GitHub site.

Comment: update the nuget package. After updating to the following versions, the exception is no longer thrown: ```<package id="NServiceBus" version="5.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="NServiceBus.Host" version="6.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="NServiceBus.SqlServer" version="2.0.2" targetFramework="net45" />````

Answer (score 0):

- Download and run "Particular Service Platform" from http://particular.net/downloads
- Choose NServiceBus (and allow it to install chocolatey too)

Comment: I am looking for a solution where I do not have to install additional components. I want to package and distribute my application just as I've done before v5. I will keep your suggestion in mind in the case I have to abandon my current approach.